# Getting rows where date=today+2 weeks to the future from all years in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server with a bunch of columns. I'd need to pull the data straight to excel and only include these three columns with all rows where 'Date' includes values from today + 2 weeks to the future from every year.

I'm really a beginner with SQL, so a help with the query would save me hours.

| Date | Zipcode | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-07 00.00.00.000 | 1725 | GB |
| 2022-14-07 00.00.00.000 | 1366 | GB |
| 2020-12-06 00.00.00.000 | 1677 | GB |
| 2022-12-05 00.00.00.000 | 9747 | GB |

Comment: please tag your rdms

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle would be this:

```
select [column names you want] from table_name where date > sysdate+14;
```

In SQL Server:

```
select [column names you want] from table_name where date >  
DATEADD(week, 2, DATEDIFF(date, 0, date));
```

Comment: Returns 0 rows. Can that original formatting be an issue, because there's datetime and not just date on "Date" column?

Comment: @Hezepena I edited my answer to apply the date part of timestamp in query

Comment: I suggest you use `>= DATEADD(week, 2, cast(GETDATE as date))` rather than that obtuse DATEDIFF logic. Far more readable and obvious. And OP - make your life easier by following the rules for [regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16).